# how to store list values to database

Tags: sharepoint

How to store list values to Sql server database?
Anybodies have any idea about this?

Comment: Normally, you would do this by iterating through the list with a loop and adding each record individually.  It will be hard to get specific advice without specifying which programming language you're using, which type of SQL server, and the source/structure/content of the list.

Because this is a programming question, it's likely to get moved over to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Technically the data already is in a SQL Server database.

Comment: Funny: I had not noticed the "sharepoint" tag when I made the initial comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to this, Codeplex has several SSIS ways of doing it here http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/

There are products which can do it too. http://www.simego.com/products/Data-Synchronisation-Studio

Depending on the data you could use the access view or export to excel and then import...

I'd almost suggest moving this back to serverfault.com

If you want to program it your self, you will probably need to look at the List web service.

I have some code(c#) that pulled from a wss2 site and pushed it to a wss3 site which I could take sections out to show you -

But I think you need to add a bit more detail to your question.